# Cannot read property getValue of Undefined - Google Piechart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm using a Google Piechart and the data on the chart should be displayed while the user click on it. I tried using the below code but it gives me an error Cannot read property getValue.

I tried displaying the selectedItem.row value and it works fine but data.getValues is not fetching any desired value from the chart.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawItems(num));    
var data; 
var chart;

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart,table package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawItems(num));    
var data; 
var chart;

function drawItems(num) 
{
    var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
        url: "getpiechartdata.php",
        data: "q="+num,
        dataType:"json",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
    var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);
    var options = {
        width: 700,
        height: 200,
        is3D: true,
        chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
    };
    // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new      
    google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    function selectHandler() {
        try
        {
            var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
            if (selectedItem) {
                var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                alert('The user selected ' + topping);
            }
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            alert(err.message);
        }}
    chart.draw(piechartdata, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select',        
                                            selectHandler);  
}
```

Comment: This isn't PHP or MySQL. It's Javascript.

Comment: you never assigned anything to the variable `data`. What do you expect `data.getValue()` to return?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I am not sure if you are on the right track with me. Please find the link below for google chart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

`getValue` is a method of the `google.visualization.DataTable` object. You assigned this to the variable `piechartdata`, not `data`, so it should be:

```
var topping = piechartdata.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
```

See the `Hello Charts` example on the documentation page you linked to.